# how put introduction in table of content without count like chapter

Tags: document-configuration

The introduction doesn't appear in table of content. How I can do it in the following example.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\title{Operation research}
\author{Dr.C. Andrey Vinajera-Zamora}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \maketitle
\chapter*{Introduction}
In recent years the operation research has played an important role in ...
\chapter{Operation research}
the operation research is ....
\section{Lineal Programming}
 The lineal programming is considered
 \chapter{Solution methods}
 Some solution methods are
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\frontmatter`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\title{Operation research}
\author{Dr.C. Andrey Vinajera-Zamora}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}   
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
        \thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
In recent years the operation research has played an important role in ...

\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{3}
\chapter{Operation research}
the operation research is ....
\section{Lineal Programming}
 The lineal programming is considered
 \chapter{Solution methods}
 Some solution methods are
\end{document}
```

EDIT: here is a full solution for your additional questions using `\setcounter`, etc.

Comment: this example put the table of contents before title and the page number must begin with introduction.

Comment: It put TOC before title because that's how you set it up.  Just switch them. The page numbering technically is a separate question, but that answer is easy to find.

Comment: I have fixed all your additional issues in the edited code above.